# How to unpersist a table broadcasted using broadcastjoin?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark's Broadcast join will broadcast copy of data to each executor. Once the join operation is complete shouldn't we unpersist the copy on each executor? Or does spark handle it internally ?

Comment: spark does all the transformations lazily ... join is not an action .... unless and until you perform any action like (count , save ... etc) join will not be performed ... again it depends on busniess logic where to unpersist parent D's or not ... spark handle it internally? yes ... when there is scarcity or RAM Garbage collector will remove old and unused datasets and create room for further execution

Comment: Let us say we broadcast a table of size 2 GB. When does Spark unpersists the broadcasted data across executors? When the action is complete or Performs a GC when RAM is full ?

Comment: When the action is complete or Performs a GC when RAM is full ? yes ... unless and until you call unpersist it will keep in memory ... and down the line of program execution if RAM usage is high GC will clean up stale datasets.